# Get notified when element added/removed to array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I wanted to be notified when an element added/removed from an array. If we are not talking about arrays, for example to be notified when a string is changed, there is a good solution in swift:

```
private var privateWord: String?
var word: String? {
    get {
        return privateWord
    }
    set {
        if newValue != "" {
            notifyThatWordIsChanged()
        } else {
            notifyThatWordIsEmpty()
        }
        privateWord = newValue
    }
}
```

Can we achive a similar result, when I add/remove an element to an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create proxy like class/struct that will have same interface as array, will store standard array under the scenes and will act on behalf of store array. Here is small example:

```
struct ArrayProxy<T> {
    var array: [T] = []

    mutating func append(newElement: T) {
        self.array.append(newElement)
        print("Element added")
    }

    mutating func removeAtIndex(index: Int) {
        print("Removed object \(self.array[index]) at index \(index)")
        self.array.removeAtIndex(index)
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> T {
        set {
            print("Set object from \(self.array[index]) to \(newValue) at index \(index)")
            self.array[index] = newValue
        }
        get {
            return self.array[index]
        }
    }
}

var a = ArrayProxy<Int>()
a.append(1)
```

Comment: This is a good workaround - however it must be taken into account that all other array methods (like map, sort, etc.) and properties are not available unless manually wrapped in a similar way

Comment: @Antonio Yeah but i guess it easy to access underlying array. `a.array = a.array.map { ... }`

Comment: Yeah it's just I wanted to point out that it's not a real `Array`, and it's not *like* an `Array` (meaning that you cannot pass it to functions expecting an instance of an array). Mine is not a critique though - just a clarification. The idea is good, but of course it's not a solution for all cases

Comment: So tired of subclassing. Why can't we just have observation?

Comment: @Antonio Yes, you'd probably want it to implement and forward all `MutableCollection`, `RandomAccessCollection` `RangeReplaceableCollection`, & `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` methodsso that it can be used as any other collection (including with `.map` and friends).

Comment: @devios: A bit painful, yes, but it's a single utility class that's infinitely reusable.  Especially if your `ArrayProxy.init()` implementation were to take `willSet:(Int,T)->()?` & `didSet:(Int,T)->()?` closures.