# Property observers on Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I want to call a delegate method when a new item is added to my dictionary.
For single value properties the `didSet(newValue)` observer works fine. But for my dictionary it seems that the newUser argument below returns the full dictionary.

```
var userIdKeyedDict:Dictionary<String, User> = [:] {
    didSet(newUser) {
    println("Updating userIdKeyedDict")
    self.delegate.didAddUser(newUser)
} 
willSet(newUser) {
  println("Will set \(newUser)")
}
```

}

The output from `willSet(newUser)` is:

> Will set [3E33BD4D-6F48-47FC-8612-565250126E51: User: userId: Optional("3E33BD4D-6F48-47FC-8612-565250126E51"), listenerUUID: Optional("77D01D6F-D017-EF9E-55A9-78570E455C51"), beaconUUID: nil]

As more items are added the `newUser` simply contains the entire dictionary.

How can I get a handle on just the new item added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it. `Dictionary` is not a class. You cannot override its functions and observe properties. Here is an example with array-like object that can observe when elements are added, removed, etc.
[Get notified when element added/removed to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041493/get-notified-when-element-added-removed-to-array/27041805#27041805)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use subscripts, these provide a flexible way to assign keys subscript values, allowing code process before and after updates to a dictionary or internal object structure. For more information regarding subscripts checkout the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html

I've included some example code to help.

```
class User {
    var userId:String = NSUUID.init().UUIDString
    var name:String = "Your Users Name"
}

class UserDictionary {
    var users = [String:User]()
    subscript(userId:String) -> User? {
        get {
            return users[userId]
        } set {
            // if newValue is nil then you are about to remove user
            users[userId] = newValue
            // do after value processing.
            print("[\(userId)]=\(newValue)")
        }
    }
}

var userdict = UserDictionary()
let user = User()
userdict[user.userId] = user
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to calculate differences between two dictionaries, you could remember the previous state of your dictionary. Whenever `willSet` ( or `didSet`) get triggered you could then calculate the difference between the previous state of your dictionary and the new state. The difference is your change, e.g. removed or added elements.